# operator= in c++ (11) working direction

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm doing a Little rational class for my Project and I overload all aritmethic operators. Well, when I try to overload operator= I have a Little and now I don't know if is my problem (i don't know how it Works) or problem of my wroten code (i wrote it bad) here's the code:

```
class rational{

   public:
      double& operator=(double& d){
         d= this->num/this->den;
         return d;
      }
      double& operator=(rational& r){
            double d= r.num/r.den;
            return d;
      }
      double& operator=(){
            double d= this->num/this->den;
            return d;
      }
}
```

Ok, what's wrong? what's right? (i think that all is wrong haha)

My goal is do that:

```
int main(){
    rational r(4, 5);
    double d= r;
}
```

Can I do it? if yes, how?

Comment: Are you showing us the entire class or only part of it? If it's the whole thing, you need to define a constructor that takes 2 doubles, not assignment operators to get your example to compile. Also, typical `operator=` implementations return a reference to the same class instance, not a reference to the input argument.

Comment: I think you're looking for `operator double`.

Comment: THANKS!! I don't know that exists operator double...thanks! Then... can I overload "all" types operators? I didn't know that THANKS for all the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want an assignment operator for this purpose - you should instead overload a conversion operator; e.g.

```
class rational {
  private: 
    int num;
    int den; 

  public: 
    // ... 
    operator double() { return double(num) / double(den); }
};
```

This will allow

```
rational r(4, 5);
double d = double(r); // d = 0.8
```

The assignment operators should be used for changing the state of an existing object, if that's something you want to allow. You probably would not want to allow assignment of a double to a rational there is no unambiguous meaning for such an operation. However, you might want to provide helpers for assigning an int, say, in addition to the usual one for assigning another rational:

```
rational &operator=(const rational &rhs)
{
    num = rhs.num;
    den = rhs.den;
    return *this;
}

rational &operator=(int rhs)
{
    num = rhs;
    den = 1;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's too difficult find how operators work if you don't have any teacher... this is useful for me Thanks!

Comment: @user2688108 Was this answer sufficient? If so, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Here I think a [user-defined conversion `operator`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/language_ref/cast_operator.html) would be more appropriate.

```
class rational {
public: 
    rational( int iNum, int iDen ) : num( iNum ), den( iDen ) {}

    // ... 
    operator double() { return (double)num / (double)den; }

private: 
    int num;
    int den;
};

int main()
{
    rational r( 1, 2 );
    double n = r;

    std::cout << r << std::endl; // output 0.5
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a little live example to illustrate this : http://ideone.com/I0Oj66

---

About the *copy assignment `operator=`* :

> A copy assignment operator of class `T` is a non-template non-static member function with the name `operator=` that takes exactly one parameter of type `T`.

The [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) is used to change an existing object.

You can use it for example to copy the state of another object :

```
rational &operator=( const rational &rhs )
{
    num = rhs.num;
    den = rhs.den;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I repeat for all! Thanks! that is the goal i want to achieve